# Filtering a stream based on its values in a toMap collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a situation where I have `Player` objects in a development project, and the task is simply measuring the distance and returning results which fall under a certain threshold. Of course, I'm wanting to use streams in the most concise manner possible.

Currently, I have a solution which maps the stream, and then filters via an iterator:

```
Stream<Player> str = /* source of my player stream I'm filtering */;
Map<Player, Double> dists = str.collect(Collectors.toMap(...)); //mapping function
Iterator<Map.Entry<Player, Double>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if (itr.next().getValue() <= radiusSquared) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

However, what I'd like to achieve is something which performs this filtering while the stream is being operated upon, something which says "if this predicate fails, do not collect", to attempt and save the second iteration. Additionally, I don't want to calculate the distances twice, so doing a filter via the mapping function, and then re-mapping isn't a plausible solution.

The only real viable solution I've thought of is mapping to a `Pair<A, B>`, but if there's native support for some form of binary stream, that'd be better.

Is there native support for this in java's stream API?

Comment: show your mapping function as well

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I'm not sure how it's relevant, it takes the `Player` objects from the stream and uses an irrelevant method to get the distance. How that's done isn't really relevant to the actual question at hand (filtering based upon that returned value). pseudo-code wise it's basically the same as `streamPlayer.distance(origin)` where `origin` is outside of the stream

Comment: What about using [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)?

Comment: I understood, you need smth like transform a stream of players to a stream of Pair<Player, Double> and then filter it and collect to a Map

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the idea is avoiding calculating the distance multiple times (so filtering based upon results of a `#toMap`, or mapping to a binary stream).

Comment: Why don't you add that data as part of the data in `Player` rather than storing it outside?

Comment: If you don't want to calculate the distance multiple times, you have to create your own `Pair` class yes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza unfortunately, I don't have control of the `Player` class contents, this is utilizing an API.

Comment: You can use a wrapper for your `Player` class. There are lots of ways to achieve this.

Comment: Well yeah, that'd basically be on par with the `Pair<A, B>` solution.  In a perfect world, I'd hope to find some form of `BinaryStream` or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filtering a `Map` afterwards is not as bad as it seems, keep in mind that iterating over a `Map` does not imply the same cost as performing a lookup (e.g. hashing).

But instead of

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Player, Double>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if (itr.next().getValue() <= radiusSquared) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

you may simply use

```
map.values().removeIf(value -> value <= radiusSquared);
```

Even if you insist on having it as part of the `collect` operation, you can do it as postfix operation:

```
Map<Player, Double> dists = str.collect(
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(p->p, p->calculate(p)),
    map -> { map.values().removeIf(value -> value <= radiusSquared); return map; }));
```

Avoiding to `put` unwanted entries in the first place is possible, but it implies manually retracing what the existing `toMap` collector does:

```
Map<Player, Double> dists = str.collect(
    HashMap::new,
    (m, p) -> { double value=calculate(p); if(value > radiusSquared) m.put(p, value); },
    Map::putAll);
```

Comment: I forgot that #values was a view and not a copy, much cleaner code-wise :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that your old-style iterator-loop could be rewritten in Java-8 using [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
map.values().removeIf(dist -> dist <= radiusSquared);
```

So it does not actually that bad. Don't forget that `keySet()` and `values()` are modifiable.

If you want to solve this using single pipeline (for example, most of the entries are to be removed), then bad news for you. Seems that current Stream API does not allow you to do this without explicit use of the class with pair semantics. It's quite natural to create a `Map.Entry` instance, though already existing option is `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` which has quite long and unpleasant name:

```
str.map(player -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(player, getDistance(player)))
   .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > radiusSquared)
   .toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue);
```

Note that it's likely that in Java-9 there will be `Map.entry()` static method, so you could use `Map.entry(player, getDistance(player))`. See [JEP-269](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269) for details.

As usual my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library has some syntactic sugar to solve this problem in cleaner way:

```
StreamEx.of(str).mapToEntry(player -> getDistance(player))
                .filterValues(dist -> dist > radiusSquared)
                .toMap();
```

And regarding the comments: yes, `toMap()` collector uses one-by-one insert, but don't worry: bulk inserts to map rarely improve the speed. You even cannot pre-size the hash-table (if your map is hash-based) as you don't know much about the elements being inserted. Probably you want to insert a million of objects with the same key: allocating the hash-table for million entries just to discover that you will have only one entry after insertion would be too wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to have one iteration and calculate distances only once, then you could do this:

```
Stream<Player> str = /* source of my player stream I'm filtering */;
Map<Player, Double> dists = new HashMap<>();
str.forEach(p -> {
    double distance = /* calculate distance */;
    if (distance <= radiusSquared) {
        dists.put(p, distance);
    }
});
```

No collector any more, but is it that important?

Comment: Not important, no. This is also viable, essentially flips multiple `Pair` objects with multiple `put` operations.

Comment: But there are multiple `put` operations anyway, right? Even if they are hidden inside a collector.

Comment: I've just looked at `Collector` and `Map` sources and it looks even worse. Collector not only does multiple `put` operation, it also checks if there is a value for a key, and if there is, it throws an exception. Might be a good thing, but if you're sure that there are no duplicate players, then doing multiple puts manually is more efficient.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed that Collectors#toMap did a bulk insertion to the map. Interesting!

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov: actually, it performs a `merge` operation which combines `put` and duplicate check in one. Even when using `put`, no duplicate `put` is needed, as it already returns the old value if there was one. Don’t judge from the `default` implementation of `merge`—all maps override it with a more efficient one.

Comment: Rogue: what kind of bulk operation do you image when the stream processes elements one by one? In order to do bulk processing, you need an intermediate storage (that’s what happens when using parallel streams), but that storage needs to be filled as well. Since there is no magic storage that could be filled significantly better than the target storage, the target storage is filled directly in the case of sequential `collect` operations. In the case of parallel collection, each thread will have a storage of the same type (i.e. a `Map`) and then `putAll` will be used to merge them.